# Highcharts: struggling to understand axis padding

Tags: highcharts

According to the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.minPadding), y axis padding is as follows:

> Padding of the min value relative to the length of the axis. A padding of 0.05 will make a 100px axis 5px longer. This is useful when you don't want the lowest data value to appear on the edge of the plot area. Defaults to 0.05.

But consider this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag73yvbL/1/), at the two places I've marked with a comment.

What I'd expect is that increasing the `minPadding` from 1.0 to 10.0 would open up a gap between the line and the bottom of the chart (so that the y axis effectively then starts at a negative value)... but it doesn't have any effect at all.

It seems that there is a block on this padding value making the axis go negative (in order to open up the desired padding).  But the docs say that it should make the axis longer, without any reference to this being dependent on the data being displayed, and where that data is relative to zero.

Furthermore, I'd not expect just changing one of the data values from slightly positive to slightly negative would have such a whopping effect.

I thought I understood highcharts axis padding, but clearly I do not!

Comment: How about setting negative min: http://jsfiddle.net/9g7fhwpv/ ?

Comment: Yes I already have that option available, but I prefer the padding setting because it should in theory be more applicable in a variety of situations, for different datasets with different ranges... if the reloaded data ranges from -20 to 50 then setting a min of -10 will cut it off.  I had always thought that `minPadding` was meant to deal with this, allowing a lower padding that is a percentage of the data range being plotted.

Comment: Set the [softThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.softThreshold) as false, example: http://jsfiddle.net/wzkhuo9t/

Comment: Genius.  That's it.  Thanks.  If you post as an answer I can mark it as correct.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I posted the answer ;)

Comment: @SebastianBochan please see my comment on your answer... doesn't work for `areaspline` series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the softThreshold parameter as a false.

```
 series: [{
    softThreshold: false,
    data: [29.9, 1.5, 6.4, 29.2, 44.0, 76.0, 35.6, 48.5, 16.4, 94.1, 5.6, 0.4] 
 }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wzkhuo9t

Comment: Two years later I've just discovered that the `softThreshold` fix doesn't have any effect for series of type `areaspline`... even though it does for `spline`... see http://jsfiddle.net/zxbw9n4c/ ... what is the solution to get the "expected" min padding for `areaspline` series?

Comment: It looks like a bug, so thanks for reporting it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8911

Comment: It looks like a bug, so thanks for reporting it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8911

Comment: A couple of years on, I'm still struggling with the whole concept of threshold combined with padding!  Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8j9ztoLg/ ... `minPadding` has no effect at all when `goNegative` is false... I want padding to apply to the *actual data*, regardless of where the `threshold` is!  (And I don't want to use a custom `tickPositioner` because from experience I don't do as good a job at positioning ticks as highcharts does!)

Comment: Here is my attempt at a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/dLvy60mz/ ... using the default tick positions from highcharts and adjusting at top and bottom if necessary.  Downside is that if the padding is made large, the default tick spacing calculated by highcharts is no longer appropriate... too close together.